# Problem when setting a modern site page which have "+" sign inside its url, as the home page for my site collection will show "page not found" error

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience, modern-pages, homepage

I am working on a SharePoint online team site collection and have created a new modern site page named as "CompnayA+CO". The URL for the page will be:

```
https://***.sharepoint.com/SitePages/CompnayA+Co.aspx
```

I can access the page without any problem. Then I set this page as the home page for our site collection, instead of the current "home.aspx" page. But now when I access the site using this URL:

```
https://***.sharepoint.com/
```

i will be redirected to a page with this URL (where the + sign has been replaced with an empty character):

```
https://***.sharepoint.com/SitePages/CompnayA Co.aspx
```

and as a result, I will get a "Page not found" error. Can anyone advice on this problem?

Thanks

Comment: The plus sign (+) is being translated to an URI-encoded space. While the plus sign is allowed nowdays in O365 under certain circumstances, I would still avoid using it. Simply: Don't use a plus sign.

Comment: @Christoffer but as i mentioned i can access the page directly using this url which contain "+" `https://***.sharepoint.com/SitePages/CompnayA+Co.aspx` but setting this as home page,, will cause the problem

Comment: The path of least resistance would be to drop the plus sign. It can cause other issues down the road as well.

Comment: @HeatherSolomon thanks for ur rely. but if the "+" sign will cause problems when setting it as the home page and will cause other issues down the road as you mentioned, then why sharepoint did not prevent us from creating pages which have the "+" sign in it? does sharepoint assume that we need to know url format and supported characters before creating pages. sharepoint is designed for non-IT people to create items and pages.. not talking about allowing them even to create sites!!! and at the end we realize that pages with "+" sign can not be set as home pages!!

Comment: @johnG, it is frustrating for sure. As a general rule of thumb it is best to stick to the alphanumeric characters and minimize special characters as much as possible. While several special characters are allowed in URLs, odd things like this can crop up. Google also discourages the use of the + character in URLs. If you search online you can find all sorts of posts from people trying to fix issues with the + character in their URL that are using other products and services.